# ajaxlink refresh window after "delete"

Tags: ajax, yii, csrf

Yii: 1.1.15

I have a list in my view and behind every row an ajaxLink to delete the row. It works but the browser does not refresh automatically ... with STRG-R it refreshes and the deleted row disappers.
My code:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('X',
  Yii::app()->createUrl('forumkommentar/delete', array("id" => $kommentar->id)), array(
   'type' => 'POST',
   'data' => array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken),
//       'data' => 'js:{"data":' . $kommentar->id . '}',
//       'success' => 'js:function(string){ document.getElementById("' . $kommentar->id . '").remove(); }'
), array(
   'class' => 'btn btn-danger small-btn',
   'confirm' => 'Are you sure?', //Confirmation
));
```

I think I need the two commented lines above to refresh the window - but it does not work.

My questions:

1. How can I combine the two "data"-lines? (line 4 and 5)
2. What is wrong in my code - or how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Firs, you are making ajax request with `POST` type, so you can't use url parameters, because url parameters are `GET` parameters. Therefore I think this can be helpful:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('X',
   Yii::app()->createUrl('forumkommentar/delete'), array(
  'type' => 'POST',
  'data' => array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken, "kommentar" => $kommentar->id),
   //'success' => 'js:function(string){ document.getElementById("' . $kommentar->id . '").remove(); }'
  ), array(
  'class' => 'btn btn-danger small-btn',
  'confirm' => 'Are you sure?', //Confirmation
));
```

Now, you can access `$_POST['kommentar']` in the `actionDelete()` of `ForumkommentarController`.

Comment: That  is not possible. The deletion does not happen. And also the  browser does not refresh.